# How to use QPainter on QPixmap

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsscene, qpainter, qpixmap

I'm a newbie to Qt/Embedded. I want to use `QPainter` to draw stuff on a `QPixmap`, which will be added to `QGraphicsScene`. Here is my code. But it does not show the drawings on the pixmap. It shows only the black pixmap.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QMainWindow *win1 = new QMainWindow();
  win1->resize(500,500);
  win1->show();


  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(win1);
  QGraphicsView view(scene, win1);
  view.show();
  view.resize(500,500);

  QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap(500,500);
  scene->addPixmap(*pix);

  QPainter *paint = new QPainter(pix);
  paint->setPen(*(new QColor(255,34,255,255)));
  paint->drawRect(15,15,100,100);

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `paint->setPen(*(new QColor(255,34,255,255)));` what an horrible memory leak! Just do  `paint->setPen(QColor(255,34,255,255));`

Comment: QPainter leaks too, it also suppose to be used on stack.

Answer (score 23):

You need to do the painting on the bitmap **before** you add it to the scene. When you add it to the scene, the scene will use it to construct a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` object, which is also returned by the `addPixmap()` function. If you want to update the pixmap after it has been added, you need to call the `setPixmap()` function of the returned `QGraphicsPixmapItem` object.

So either:

```
...
QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap(500,500);
QPainter *paint = new QPainter(pix);
paint->setPen(*(new QColor(255,34,255,255)));
paint->drawRect(15,15,100,100);
scene->addPixmap(*pix); // Moved this line
...
```

or:

```
...
QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap(500,500);
QGraphicsPixmapItem* item(scene->addPixmap(*pix)); // Save the returned item
QPainter *paint = new QPainter(pix);
paint->setPen(*(new QColor(255,34,255,255)));
paint->drawRect(15,15,100,100);
item->setPixmap(*pix); // Added this line
...
```

Answer (score 14):

`QPixmap` should be created without `new` keyword. It's usually passed by value or reference, not by pointer. One of the reasons is that `QPixmap` is not capable of tracking its changes. When you add a pixmap to a scene using `addPixmap`, only the current pixmap is used. Further changes will not affect the scene. So you should call `addPixmap` after you make changes.

Also you need to destroy `QPainter` before you use the pixmap to ensure that all changes will be written to the pixmap and to avoid memory leak.

```
QPixmap pix(500,500);
QPainter *paint = new QPainter(&pix);
paint->setPen(QColor(255,34,255,255));
paint->drawRect(15,15,100,100);
delete paint;
scene->addPixmap(pix);
```

Comment: is it the same to encapsulate the `QPainter` calls between `QPainter::begin` and `QPainter::end` instead of destroy it?

Comment: `begin` is called automatically in the constructor. You can call `end`  without deleting the object and call `begin` later to reuse the object. Of course, you must finally destroy it some time. But it's more convenient to create `QPainter` without `new` to make it deleted automatically. There is no point in preserving the same painter between two paint actions. Constructing painters is a cheap operation.

Comment: This answer was *very* helpful to me.  I was accidentally calling `QPainter::end()` *after* updating a `QPixmap` value instance.  This caused a segmentation fault that was difficult to fix.  Yes, `QPixmap` is normally created with `new` keyword, but ctor `QPainter(PaintDevice*)` (or method `begin(PaintDevice*)`) requires a pointer.  Be careful about using a pointer to a value instance of `QPixmap`!