# Replace a part of a QPixMap with a smaller QPixMap

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and Qt Graphics API.

I have a larger `QPixMap` and a smaller `QPixMap`. I need to replace a portion (a `QRect`) of the larger one with the smaller one.

How am I supposed to achieve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

`QPainter::drawPixmap()` does not update the image represented by pImage->p_PixMap.

**Code**

```
class GraphicImage : public QObject,
    public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GraphicImage(QPixmap* oImage,GraphiItemCtrl* pParent);
    virtual ~GraphicImage(void);
    QPixmap* p_PixMap;
};
- - - - 
GraphicImage::GraphicImage(QPixmap* oImage,GraphiItemCtrl* pParent)
    :QGraphicsPixmapItem(*oImage), p_Parent(pParent)
{
    p_PixMap = oImage;
}
- - - - 
void GraphiItemCtrl::SetImagePortion( QString sFileName, QRect rect, QPixmap pChildPixMap )
{
    GraphicImage* pImage = map_CurrentImages[sFileName];

    if ( !pImage )
        return;

    pChildPixMap.save("test.jpg");
    QPixmap* pMap = pImage->p_PixMap;
    QPainter pPainter(pMap);

    pPainter.drawPixmap(rect, pChildPixMap);
    qDebug() << rect.topLeft();
}
```

`pChildPixMap.save("test.jpg");` saves the required portion of the image without an issue.

*NOTE* :
`pImage` is inherited from QObject and QGraphicsPixmapItem.
`pMap` is not `NULL`

Comment: You should look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888795/how-to-use-qpainter-on-qpixmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

```
void QPainter::drawPixmap(const QRect &rectangle, const QPixmap &pixmap)
```

It will draw the `pixmap` into a `rectangle` portion of the painter's target.

You may also want to use this one:

```
void QPainter::drawPixmap(const QRect &target, const QPixmap &pixmap, const QRect &source)
```

Which will draw a portion of the source into a portion of the target.

In both cases if the sizes mismatch the image will be scaled, so if you are getting poor results, you will additionally need to tweak the scaling method.

As established in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894246/qpainterdrawpixmap-doesnt-look-good-and-has-low-quality/36894419#36894419), setting `setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);` by itself does not seem to produce optimal results. If you want the best quality you will need to manually `scale()` the pixmap and then draw it, which produces much better results than scaling it on the fly while painting.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to extract the output `QPixMap` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? The "output" is just the pixmap your painter was set to draw on.

Comment: So, the target PixMap is automatically update? I will try this and get back.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris - what is `p_PixMap`? Looks like you are passing an invalid pointer to the painter.

Comment: It's a pointer to a QPixMap, which is initialized at the constructor of pImage. Anyway, I'll check. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris the code still doesn't show how and if `p_PixMap` is being properly initialized.

Comment: updated the code with the definition of `GraphicImage`.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris - so it looks like the problem is the pixmap pointer you are passing to the `GraphicImage` constructor.

Comment: But it a simple `new QPixMap(QSize)` filled with black.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris - after you paint on the pixmap, do you use `QGraphicsPixmapItem::setPixmap()` to update it? After painting on the pixmap, try `pImage->setPixmap(*pMap);` Pixmaps are implicitly shared, so every modification detaches the data from the source, so you will need to call this after every painting. So it may look like you are painting on the same pixmap, but the painting itself creates a new pixmap, so you need to update it manually.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Quick pseudocode:

```
QPainter painter(pixmap1);
painter.drawPixmap(QRect, pixmap2);
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qpainter.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to extract the output `QPixMap` ?

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris The pixmap where you'll invoke `drawPixmap` will be drawn onto

Comment: This is some dangerous pseudocode. You should hold the painter by value.

Comment: @KubaOber I stand corrected, most Qt memory management is done under the hood with a parent-child hierarchy (so naked allocations - that I usually detest - aren't a problem).. but in this case there was a leak. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcoA. That's too broad of a generalization: You have the **option** to *leverage* a parent-child relationship between `QObject`s for memory management purposes. It's **truly and purely optional**. An object can hold child objects by value and then the C++ semantics ensure that the children get destroyed when needed. E.g. `class Foo : public QWidget { QLabel child1{"Hello", this}; QLabel child2{"World", this}; ... };` - the labels will be gone before the parent, and Qt has no involvement in it at all. If the lifetime of children is that of a parent, you should just hold them by value!

Comment: @MarcoA. Note the difference between the broad "most Qt memory managment" and "parent-child relationship between `QObject`s": not everything is a `QObject`. Also note that leveraging it is optional: you can, but you don't have to, and you shouldn't if the parent and child lifetimes are identical and you're the author of the parent class.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, I was mostly referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1651647/1938163) kind of common widget paradigm (got me wondering what was the catch the first time I saw it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a painter on the destination pixmap to draw the source pixmap in a given destination rectangle:

```
void draw(QPixmap &dst, const QRect &dstRect, const QPixmap &src) {
  QPainter(dst).drawPixmap(dstRect, src); 
}
```

If you're drawing multiple such pixmaps on one destination, you should hold on to the painter - it'd be wasteful to construct new painter over and over in a loop:

```
struct Replacement {
  QRect dstRect;
  QPixmap source;
};

void draw(QPixmap &dst, const QList<Replacement> &replacements) {
  QPainter painter{dst};
  for (auto & r : replacements)
    painter.drawPixmap(r.dstRect, r.source);
}
```